# Why can't I call {event_summary}, but I can call every other event property? (Solspace Calendar)

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

Here's my template file:

```
{embed="_includes/header" 
    entry_title="{exp:channel:entries status="Open|Closed" channel="settings" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|trackbacks"}{title}{/exp:channel:entries}" 
    entry_id="{exp:channel:entries status="Open|Closed" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|trackbacks"}{entry_id}{/exp:channel:entries}"}

{exp:channel:entries channel="events"}
<section id="page" class="{segment_2} {segment_3} standard {if page_has_long_menu}long-menu{/if}">
    <div class="bg-left">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="bg">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <nav id="sub-menu">
                <!--{embed="navigations/{segment_2}"}-->
                {exp:structure:nav start_from="/en/{segment_2}/" max_depth="1" current_class="active"}
            </nav>

            <img src="{events_page_header}" alt="{events_page_title}" width="1020" height="240" />
            <h2>{events_page_title}</h2>
        </header>
    </div>

    <div class="content events-content">
        <div class="wrapper">
            {if title}<h2>{calendar_title}</h2>{/if}

            {calendar_description}

            <div class="calendar">
                <div id="events-cal">
                    {exp:calendar:mini
                        calendar_name="events"
                        enable="pagination"
                        date_range_start="2013-10-01"}
                    {/exp:calendar:mini}
                </div>

                <ul id="events-summaries">
                {exp:calendar:events}
                    <li>
                        {if event_all_day}
                            {event_start_date format="%F %j, %Y"}
                        {if:else}
                            {event_start_date format="%F %j, %Y"} - {event_end_date format="%F %j, %Y"}
                        {/if}
                        <br />
                        <a href="{path='calender/event'}/{event_id}/">
                            {event_title} || 
                        </a>
                        {event_id} || 
                        {event_author} || 
                        {event_summary}
                        <p>{location}</p>
                    </li>

                    {if no_results}
                    <li>No Results</li>
                    {/if}
                {/exp:calendar:events}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
{/exp:channel:entries}

{embed="_includes/footer"}
```

About 3/4 of the way down you can see me attempting to call {event_title} and {event_summary}, [as per the documentation here.](http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/events/#examples)

And the output....

[output http://puu.sh/4Teja.png](http://puu.sh/4Teja.png)

It doesn't output summary, **but it IS outputting title, ID, etc...**. Why can I call every property of the event BUT the summary?

Investigating further, I went into PHPMyAdmin, into the `exp_calendar_events` table -- and found out that there is no field for event summary.

Why is this? Is my installation bugged or am I missing something?

(I created `Test Event Numba One` by going `Content -> Publish -> Calender: Events` in the CMS)

Answer (score 2):

Any event data outside of the [variables listed here](http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/events/#variables) is up to you to create via standard custom Channel fields.

So `{event_summary}` will only parse if you've created your own custom field called `event_summary`.

Also, side note - what you're doing at the top of your template is a little loopy - two Channel Entries calls just to get the title and entry id! At the very least you should disable `custom_fields` on those (as you're not using them) - but without knowing why they're there in the first place it's hard for me to advise a better way.

Comment: I agree. I would try using {exp:calendar:events} alone on a blank template to test if you can output {event_summary} then. If you can't, then maybe event_summary is not a custom field in the "Calendar: Events" custom field group?